# Logging of hard errors (eg. 500) not working

Tags: django

I've got the following in my settings, yet, 500 errors aren't being written to my djangoerrors file. I've confirmed that the file exists in this directory (I created it myself and the permissions are set to 777).

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/opt/python/log/djangoerrors.log'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Any thoughts on why errors are not being written to this file?

thanks!